# How to automate openssl s_client?

Tags: openssl

I wonder is there any way to send query to initiated session OpenSSL. Something like?

`openssl s_client -connect some.secure-server.com:443 < data.txt`

Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work. Any ideas how to modify it to make it work?

Thanks,
Jonas

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why are you thanking the Jona, clearly the Jona haven't helped you.

What part of [the documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) didn't the student understand?

懶散的人!

```
禪師無@北京:~ $ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = ZA, O = Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd., CN = Thawte SGC CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
 1 s:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1907 bytes and written 397 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: E17E53235F9870A35F3F477AE7E8692875A46DA68F4E0FAC4D0A81AF8CFAE5B8
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 3A8C9540963D5538063D74B5BC2174CEF1145917F02FCD6111D246D9357EB90B7E79076CCD597D37BD2C3FACBE0377B6
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 1a b6 4a e9 9e fd 36 e2-74 0a 05 ba 4c bf b3 d3   ..J...6.t...L...
    0010 - f1 7e 67 8b 81 d3 af cb-52 3c d1 8f 3f b0 97 5f   .~g.....R<..?.._
    0020 - 67 30 ea 32 7e f2 c6 01-5e 73 53 6d f3 d0 bb 65   g0.2~...^sSm...e
    0030 - fa b5 03 af 76 0d 9f 25-93 f8 b4 70 1f d7 25 3d   ....v..%...p..%=
    0040 - ec 09 82 81 a0 48 11 41-0b 93 bf 08 df 25 a6 87   .....H.A.....%..
    0050 - 5a 11 13 ad 0d 6e 58 a2-22 9c 96 be 38 cc 3c 51   Z....nX."...8.<Q
    0060 - ff 35 99 cd 46 f4 b9 9c-07 7e c9 e4 31 69 55 83   .5..F....~..1iU.
    0070 - 58 41 a6 83 f1 87 7c d5-38 ac ec 7f 65 6d b6 a6   XA....|.8...em..
    0080 - 3a 68 aa 68 4e 5b b4 6d-81 91 a0 7d fd cc 56 db   :h.hN[.m...}..V.
    0090 - ad da c9 74                                       ...t

    Start Time: 1288632388
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```